# input in C++ -> Python platform

Tags: python, c++, input

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int CurrVal = 0, val = 0;
    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin>> CurrVal){
        int cnt = 1; // store the count for current value we're processing 

        while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers 
            if (val == CurrVal) 
                ++cnt;
            else {  // otherwise, print the count for the previous value 
                    std::cout << CurrVal << " occurs "
                    << cnt << " times " << std::endl; 
                    CurrVal = val; // remember the new value 
                    cnt = 1; // reset the counter
            }
        } // while loop ends here
        std::cout << CurrVal << " Occurs " << cnt << " times " << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

}

# python

Currval = 0 

val = 0 

if (Currval=int(input(" "))): # ?? My head is stuck on this.
```

After learning Python, I'm learning C++ from "C++ Primer 5th".

To understand this code, I thought how it could be implemented by Python.

My questions is:

How can I convert `if (std::cin>> CurrVal)` from C++ to Python code?

```
cnt = 1 
D = True
A = int(input(""))
while D:
    C = True
    cnt =1 
    while(C):
  
        B = int(input("\n-1 == quit "))
 
        if B != -1:
            C = B
        if A == B:
 
            cnt += 1 
        else:
   
            print(A,"occured",cnt," Times")
            A = B
            cnt =1

        if B == -1:
            break 
    break
```

My translating from what I understood is above.

Even if I know "if ( var = int(input("")) ): " could make an error, Just curious about how to do. "stream in input" in Python.

Comment: Don't you want to know what issues are there in this C++ code?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to transform that input part. I did it several times through VS code. Intuitively, I know what the program is for even though I didn't fully understand the data flow. But, that's not my point of question.

Comment: In Python, how do you stream in input stopping at the first whitespace, character-by-character, converting to an int, and failing that set the error condition on the input stream, and setting the value to zero?

Comment: Question : How to change ? those input parts from cpp to python

Comment: @Eljay, I don't understand which point you're talking about. I am so sorry about that. Could you tell me again?

Comment: translating code from one language to another requires two steps A) understand every details about what the original code does B) write code in the other language that does the same. Eljay is talking about A) and how you would do B)

Comment: I know that It's weird in Python  "  If  ( Var = int(input("")) ): ". but, Just wondering how could it be done, by experts? @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

> My questions is:
>
> How can I convert `if (std::cin>> CurrVal)` from C++ to Python code?

**Answer**: You cant explicitly convert code one from another. They are different languages, with different way of working, arthmetic semantics, way of operator works. (there is some project which do "similar" thing, but it is only the illusion You could do it easily and that it easy task: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/ )

In C++ (and even more in Python) that kind of code is just bad, dirty **and You should not write like this**.

You want to read variable? [Then `input()` that.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) Then want to use if-statement? [Use `if condition:`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_statement.asp). Your code want to be simpler.

**Note:** Question is irrelevant to the table of text You attached. Always narrow down your question and example scope.

EDIT because of new question raised:

> Even if I know "if ( var = int(input("")) ): " could make an error,
>
> Just curious about how to do. "stream in input" in Python.

The "[streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)" are both the same. In Python, C++ or bash. But they are processed in other set of rules (because of used language methods, built-ins, binaries - so another machine code run under the hood).

For Python input() there is some "magic" always.
But the C++'s std::cin too.
They would "stop" taking & interpreting input from stdio ([file descriptor 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for *nix processes) differently, so You see the difference in their action.

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/ still relevant; join #c++ #c++-general on libera IRC, see this books http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1090079

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement conditional, you have have to test against either a true or false value.

`std::cin` in c++ will let you enter a variety of datatypes, so if you want an integer value you can use an `if` statement if you want to check and make sure what entered is valid.

Now in python, any input using `input` will automatically convert to a string. You need to convert it to an integer using the `int()` if you want it to be an integer. So for example

```
CurrVal = int(input("Enter the integer here: "))
```

This eliminated the need to check if you have an integer like in your code above

Side note: This C++ in the example is pretty bad so in the future, your goal is to make your code as readable as possible (never as compact and clever as possible)

Comment: Question about (std::cin >> A) // if A = 0, how could "if statement" continue? My knowledge std::cin >> A means input to A &  0 is boolean in " if (0) { }".     // Thank you for advice sincerely

Comment: If you "eliminate" that step with checking what is when the input is not integer, then the "convertion" just gone :) because operations on C++ stdin would behave not like python's input built-in.

Comment: @JeonJINo So you are correct that normally A=0 would evaluate to false. However in this certain situation we are using (std::cin >> A) and not just (A). This situation of std::cin >> A only evaluates to false when A is not an integer. For example if you entered `b` instead of `7` for CurrVal

Comment: "(never as compact and clever as possible)" - this is very good advice; You should not write code as good as You could because while debugging you always need to be double-clever (which You could not own then)

Comment: @jstraugh Wow! Understood. Like isdigit() in Python

Comment: @JeonJINo but >>> "-234".isdigit()
 would return False

Comment: I think it's due to the overflow error as the help command says.  @badasz . Because of "Out of range", it couldn't be allowed, so that returns False. That's what I understood.